# Oracle WebLogic Server Enterprise Edition for OKE Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, weblogic

I have unusual problem with Oracle WebLogic Server Enterprise Edition for OKE terraform configuration. I don't where I can fix it.  Any advice? I use this [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/weblogic-container/wlkgs/index.html)
Below source of the problem:

```
    Error: 409-EntityAlreadyExists
Provider version: 4.19.0, released on 2021-03-24. This provider is 42 updates behind to current.
Service: IdentityDynamicGroup
Error Message: Dynamic group 'weblogic-admin-instance-principal-group' already exists
OPC request ID: 3faffb01b4489f807dafc0b93df36a88/1A8209B812B70E2DD15DBE0A60C43D3F/3D2E29A52D062C250E36B98507AC14E1
Suggestion: The resource is in a conflicted state. Please retry again or contact support for help with service: IdentityDynamicGroup
  on modules/policies/groups.tf line 3, in resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_admin_instance_principal_group" 
   3: resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_admin_instance_principal_group" {
Error: 409-EntityAlreadyExists
Provider version: 4.19.0, released on 2021-03-24. This provider is 42 updates behind to current.
Service: IdentityDynamicGroup
Error Message: Dynamic group 'weblogic-osms-instance-principal-group' already exists
OPC request ID: d938541a6aa4e3b32c486c2289c36ab0/C88E12EE4F6C52912E031DA0FED4D767/DD81A5ABA4C297D5070BB8051659AF88
Suggestion: The resource is in a conflicted state. Please retry again or contact support for help with service: IdentityDynamicGroup
  on modules/policies/groups.tf line 16, in resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_managed_instances_principal_group" 
  16: resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_managed_instances_principal_group" {
Error: marshaling request to a header requires not nil pointer for field: CompartmentId
  on modules/oke/nodepool/nodepools.tf line 3, in resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "wls-nodepool" 
   3: resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "wls-nodepool" {
Error: marshaling request to a header requires not nil pointer for field: CompartmentId
  on modules/oke/nodepool/nodepools.tf line 52, in resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "non-wls-nodepool" 
  52: resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "non-wls-nodepool" {
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

**Below all log file:**

```
Initializing modules...
- admin in modules/compute/admin
- bastion in modules/compute/bastion
- cluster in modules/oke/cluster
- fss in modules/fss
- mp_subscription in modules/mp-subscription
- network in modules/network
- network.admin-vcn-config in modules/network/admin-vcn-config
- network.bastion-vcn-config in modules/network/bastion-vcn-config
- network.fss-vcn-config in modules/network/fss-vcn-config
- network.oke-vcn-config in modules/network/oke-vcn-config
- network.vcn in modules/network/vcn
- nodepool in modules/oke/nodepool
- opc-key in modules/opc-key
- policies in modules/policies
- provisioner in modules/provisioner
- validators in modules/validators
Initializing provider plugins...
The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.
To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.
*provider.null: version = "~> 2.1"
*provider.template: version = "~> 2.1"
*provider.tls: version = "~> 2.0"
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.
If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
2022/01/16 17:54:29 [WARN] Log levels other than TRACE are currently unreliable, and are supported only for backward compatibility.
  Use TF_LOG=TRACE to see Terraform's internal logs.
  ----
module.nodepool.data.template_file.script: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.data.template_cloudinit_config.nodepool-config: Refreshing state...
data.oci_objectstorage_namespace.object_namespace: Refreshing state...
data.oci_identity_tenancy.tenancy: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.data.oci_containerengine_cluster_option.k8s_cluster_option: Refreshing state...
module.network.module.vcn.data.oci_core_services.all_oci_services: Refreshing state...
module.mp_subscription.data.oci_core_app_catalog_subscriptions.nodepool_mp_image_subscription[0]: Refreshing state...
data.oci_identity_regions.all_regions: Refreshing state...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.data.oci_core_services.all_oci_services[0]: Refreshing state...
module.mp_subscription.data.oci_core_app_catalog_subscriptions.admin_mp_image_subscription[0]: Refreshing state...
data.oci_identity_region_subscriptions.tenancy_region_subscriptions: Refreshing state...
module.mp_subscription.data.oci_core_app_catalog_subscriptions.bastion_mp_image_subscription[0]: Refreshing state...
data.oci_identity_regions.home-region: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad_list: Refreshing state...
module.cluster.data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad_list: Refreshing state...
module.cluster.data.template_file.ad_names[2]: Refreshing state...
module.cluster.data.template_file.ad_names[0]: Refreshing state...
module.cluster.data.template_file.ad_names[1]: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.data.template_file.ad_names[0]: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.data.template_file.ad_names[1]: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.data.template_file.ad_names[2]: Refreshing state...
module.admin.data.template_file.ingress_inputs: Refreshing state...
module.opc-key.tls_private_key.opc_key: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_listing_resource_version_agreement.admin_mp_image_agreement[0]: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_listing_resource_version_agreement.bastion_mp_image_agreement[0]: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_listing_resource_version_agreement.nodepool_mp_image_agreement[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_vcn.vcn[0]: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_listing_resource_version_agreement.nodepool_mp_image_agreement[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=2022-01-16 17:54:38.708 +0000 UTC]
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_subscription.nodepool_mp_image_subscription[0]: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_listing_resource_version_agreement.bastion_mp_image_agreement[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=2022-01-16 17:54:38.748 +0000 UTC]
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_listing_resource_version_agreement.admin_mp_image_agreement[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=2022-01-16 17:54:38.704 +0000 UTC]
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_subscription.bastion_mp_image_subscription[0]: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_subscription.admin_mp_image_subscription[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_vcn.vcn[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=ocid1.vcn.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.amaaaaaabpeboiiahlbv2xek2re6hc3vvymn5gpjcypxfpddx2ps4j2v2fsq]
module.network.module.vcn.data.oci_core_internet_gateways.internet_gateways: Refreshing state...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_internet_gateway.ig[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_nat_gateway.nat_gateway[0]: Creating...
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_subscription.nodepool_mp_image_subscription[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=compartmentId/ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaainwmoiz6gbq2wvh2vh74owxanq3hhwtq4uuulvc667hkh55lys4q/listingId/ocid1.appcataloglisting.oc1..aaaaaaaa5w6dsxlgewu73uadyboy7su3qgobq3o6kdhnx5zouzqipdq2y26q/listingResourceVersion/20.4.1-200917030044]
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_internet_gateway.ig[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=ocid1.internetgateway.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaawdv35qqchryyr3ciiyfwrbbvp3ebhm6fvyncwoobdcfjctjnm6ya]
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_subscription.admin_mp_image_subscription[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=compartmentId/ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaainwmoiz6gbq2wvh2vh74owxanq3hhwtq4uuulvc667hkh55lys4q/listingId/ocid1.appcataloglisting.oc1..aaaaaaaali6fqhd2kf3ee6bvqekiwnrsz24va4molvqmbrtxvgnlgqhbcpvq/listingResourceVersion/21.4.2-211216191700]
module.mp_subscription.oci_core_app_catalog_subscription.bastion_mp_image_subscription[0]: Creation complete after 2s [id=compartmentId/ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaainwmoiz6gbq2wvh2vh74owxanq3hhwtq4uuulvc667hkh55lys4q/listingId/ocid1.appcataloglisting.oc1..aaaaaaaacicjx6jviqczqow567tadr5ju7iy2m4vx6opyra6thql55n2nnvq/listingResourceVersion/21.4.3-211213203402]
module.opc-key.tls_private_key.opc_key: Creation complete after 3s [id=59848577c247872dad0a481d3118386b0f4b2de1]
module.admin.data.template_file.key_script: Refreshing state...
module.bastion.data.template_file.key_script: Refreshing state...
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Creating...
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Creating...
module.bastion.data.template_cloudinit_config.bastion-config: Refreshing state...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_nat_gateway.nat_gateway[0]: Creation complete after 2s [id=ocid1.natgateway.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaaekapgwu4tzt5vanvkkca5qeb4qqhn4hnj6enm457v5hwzubeeaya]
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_service_gateway.service_gateway[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_service_gateway.service_gateway[0]: Creation complete after 2s [id=ocid1.servicegateway.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaalnbebgti637iwsoafgdgseies27vwrsvnded7latcsir3thduxkq]
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_route_table.ig_route[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_route_table.nat_route[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_route_table.ig_route[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=ocid1.routetable.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaamtizu5276vfotjt42s4k5ls3ruqlu44k3nzbn3krm6b3rv2np73a]
module.network.module.fss-vcn-config.data.oci_core_vcn.oke_vcn: Refreshing state...
module.network.module.bastion-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.bastion_security_list[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.fss-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.fss_seclist[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.vcn.oci_core_route_table.nat_route[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=ocid1.routetable.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaaz6e6z3a4abxojw4qsy3hsrbd47mtbljytwgwacibenklni3ycfnq]
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.data.oci_core_subnets.oke_subnets: Refreshing state...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.lb_seclist[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.endpoint_seclist[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.private_workers_seclist[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.bastion-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.bastion_security_list[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=ocid1.securitylist.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaasminpqfj3tepktfuoyexyqsv5o7xjmy47ktjjysidasunta3kakq]
module.network.module.bastion-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.bastion_subnet[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.fss-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.fss_seclist[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=ocid1.securitylist.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaamky5wb4zhosuscbbq5vzfcpu2k6him7a5smfc7oeyrcmliplpl4q]
module.network.module.fss-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.fssubnets[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.lb_seclist[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=ocid1.securitylist.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaahzk7dn4hzw45225ufgedrvcxsgdg5rjty7dur73wvgp2ekccv34q]
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.lb_subnet[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.endpoint_seclist[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=ocid1.securitylist.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaatotuxrys7fnv4aq2o75as7kyawy7gok7upyob2ilocveejo66jbq]
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.cluster_endpoint_config_subnet[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.private_workers_seclist[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=ocid1.securitylist.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaawyt5ws5iqzu46palelea5wjqyy3qxrterjhjkcaajtxa5ios2ywa]
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.oke_workers_subnet[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.bastion-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.bastion_subnet[0]: Creation complete after 3s [id=ocid1.subnet.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaat6s7pmzpodbcb4n6hnwalxgrbkcmrllrn4pjrl4krnvdqttxhxsa]
module.network.module.bastion-vcn-config.data.oci_core_subnet.bastion_subnet[0]: Refreshing state...
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.admin-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.admin_security_list[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.admin-vcn-config.oci_core_security_list.admin_security_list[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=ocid1.securitylist.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaaefz7sfmsxxdhvo7d4jtgzokc35gtsqjs2w564ypnjvguwf5ggmhq]
module.network.module.admin-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.admin_subnet[0]: Creating...
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.cluster_endpoint_config_subnet[0]: Creation complete after 4s [id=ocid1.subnet.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaat7oz35xbyiufrdbx3bfnmdo2v6j4vrshylucgve4kfdtukuq4fuq]
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.oke_workers_subnet[0]: Creation complete after 4s [id=ocid1.subnet.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaaqbyutozci74yge64gu5ycpycuurfqf4rg5o7njafgpn7yyo52wda]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.network.module.admin-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.admin_subnet[0]: Creation complete after 4s [id=ocid1.subnet.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaaqztsjzvmjilxfnt7hcap6mqkhsv47cvakovitet5eyaf33s7icha]
module.network.module.fss-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.fssubnets[0]: Creation complete after 9s [id=ocid1.subnet.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaakk5kgmnbhdjf6cy43ddn6sjod7oozwtldpl27kpo5dwwffdi2nia]
module.network.module.oke-vcn-config.oci_core_subnet.lb_subnet[0]: Creation complete after 9s [id=ocid1.subnet.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaaw3k6p5b7ueb6cph62gz3huc3wh4kolyjwpgyodous4245c6rgfhq]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Creating...
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
module.bastion.oci_core_instance.bastion[0]: Creation complete after 1m14s [id=ocid1.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.antheljtbpeboiicm57m76yfl5fmhtn5baactrgauhg2e6qxxu7ethq3beca]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_managed_instances_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
module.policies.oci_identity_dynamic_group.oke_admin_instance_principal_group[0]: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [2m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [2m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [2m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [2m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [3m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [3m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [3m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [3m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [3m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [3m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [4m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [4m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [4m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [4m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [4m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [4m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [5m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [5m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [5m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [5m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [5m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [5m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [6m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [6m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [6m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [6m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [6m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [6m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [7m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [7m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [7m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [7m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [7m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [7m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [8m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [8m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [8m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [8m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [8m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [8m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [9m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [9m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [9m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [9m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [9m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [9m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10m20s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10m30s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10m40s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [10m50s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [11m0s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Still creating... [11m10s elapsed]
module.cluster.oci_containerengine_cluster.k8s_cluster[0]: Creation complete after 11m18s [id=ocid1.cluster.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.aaaaaaaa27zwk77jtqt5j35vkltfafdjjjdligvyy7q7mawjpcvhv365vugq]
module.cluster.data.oci_containerengine_clusters.oke_clusters: Refreshing state...
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Creating...
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.non-wls-nodepool: Creating...
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.non-wls-nodepool: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.non-wls-nodepool: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.non-wls-nodepool: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.nodepool.oci_containerengine_node_pool.wls-nodepool[0]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
Error: 409-EntityAlreadyExists
Provider version: 4.19.0, released on 2021-03-24. This provider is 42 updates behind to current.
Service: IdentityDynamicGroup
Error Message: Dynamic group 'weblogic-admin-instance-principal-group' already exists
OPC request ID: 3faffb01b4489f807dafc0b93df36a88/1A8209B812B70E2DD15DBE0A60C43D3F/3D2E29A52D062C250E36B98507AC14E1
Suggestion: The resource is in a conflicted state. Please retry again or contact support for help with service: IdentityDynamicGroup
  on modules/policies/groups.tf line 3, in resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_admin_instance_principal_group" 
   3: resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_admin_instance_principal_group" {
Error: 409-EntityAlreadyExists
Provider version: 4.19.0, released on 2021-03-24. This provider is 42 updates behind to current.
Service: IdentityDynamicGroup
Error Message: Dynamic group 'weblogic-osms-instance-principal-group' already exists
OPC request ID: d938541a6aa4e3b32c486c2289c36ab0/C88E12EE4F6C52912E031DA0FED4D767/DD81A5ABA4C297D5070BB8051659AF88
Suggestion: The resource is in a conflicted state. Please retry again or contact support for help with service: IdentityDynamicGroup
  on modules/policies/groups.tf line 16, in resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_managed_instances_principal_group" 
  16: resource "oci_identity_dynamic_group" "oke_managed_instances_principal_group" {
Error: marshaling request to a header requires not nil pointer for field: CompartmentId
  on modules/oke/nodepool/nodepools.tf line 3, in resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "wls-nodepool" 
   3: resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "wls-nodepool" {
Error: marshaling request to a header requires not nil pointer for field: CompartmentId
  on modules/oke/nodepool/nodepools.tf line 52, in resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "non-wls-nodepool" 
  52: resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "non-wls-nodepool" {
```

Let me know what you think. Thanks.

Mark E - I can't add more code because I have a red warning that " It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: We need to see the terraform code and not only the error.

Comment: We need to see the code **here** not somewhere on Dropbox. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.